# BeautifulSoup not working after the first page

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use Python's BeautifulSoup to scrape data from the following [website](http://insider.espn.com/nbadraft/results/top100/_/year/2019). The data on the website is split over four different pages. Each page has a unique link (*i.e.* http://insider.espn.com/nbadraft/results/top100/_/year/2019/set/0 for the first page, http://insider.espn.com/nbadraft/results/top100/_/year/2019/set/1 for the second page, etc.). I am able to successfully scrape the data on the first page, but when I try to scrape data for the second page onward it comes up empty. Here is the code I'm using:

```
# Import libraries
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

# Define url and request webpage
season = 2019
page = 1
url = "http://insider.espn.com/nbadraft/results/top100/_/year/{}/set/{}".format(season, page)
req = Request(url , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")

# Scrape all of the data in the table
rows = page_soup.findAll('tr')[1:]
player_stats = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')]
                for i in range(len(rows))]

# Get the column headers
headers = player_stats[0]

# Remove the first row
player_stats.pop(0)

# Convert to pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns = headers)

# Remove all rows where Name = None
df = df[~df['NAME'].isnull()]

# Remove PLAYER column because it's empty
df = df.drop(columns='PLAYER')
df
```

Any advice would be much appreciated! I'm a bit new to using BeautifulSoup, so I apologize in advance if the code isn't particularly nice or efficient.

**Update**: The links only work if opened in Chrome, which is likely what is causing the problem. Is there any way around it?

Comment: The second link does not seem to have data apparently when I Clicked!

Comment: @BernadPeter meaning when you click the second link you don't see the table with player names, height, weight, etc?

Comment: Yes. indeed! This could be an issue with website itself!

Comment: @BernadPeter Weird! I am able to see the table when I click the link. How about if you click the first link and then hit the "Next >>" button at the bottom of the table?

Comment: yes. It is just empty. I cannot post the screenshot in the comments.

Comment: Please check your html manually if the data is read completely.

Comment: @BernadPeter Oh I see the issue now. The link definitely doesn't work in Firefox. If I use Chrome, though, I can see the entire table.

Comment: did you check your 'webpage' for the desired table data in the html?

Comment: @BernadPeter When I print "webpage" for anything beyond the first page, it looks like the contents of the table aren't included. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Not sure how to overcome. Maybe you can drop an message to the espn regarding the issue. They may be able to fix it.